# Convert magento 2 module as widget

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created module referring below blog post https://www.codilar.com/blog/how-to-create-a-hello-world-module-in-magento-2/ and its working fine.. hello world print on homepage.

Now i need to use this module as a widget . Then we can use this module anywhere we need.(in CMS pages)

Is there anyone have and idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest please follow below reference site steps, which will help you to create a widget.

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/custom-widget.html
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-custom-widget/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but how to set the hello world text(from the module) to widget tittle instead of type the title

Comment: Please follow the last one it will help you display text which you want in your custom module. Else build it from the starting.